# Is asking about storing physical prints ok here?

Tags: discussion

I have several prints from 30x40 cm to 60x90 cm and storing them rolled as they are delivered takes a lot of space.
I was thinking about asking about how to store prints in flat position relatively airtight, for example by building a container.

What I would like is, in fact, links to projects I can build for that.

This is borderline, should I ask in home improvement or woodworking? but the container would be likely in acrylic or polystyrene panels, so not woodworking, and it's not home improvement either.

Comment: I would expect questions on preservation of prints to be on-topic.  However asking for links to projects sounds very close to being a shopping question.

Comment: I would say that your main problem is what you put between the prints to avoid the migration of the picture to the back of the print above it. Classic photography books will presumably do the trick, otherwise baking paper could be a cheap solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual disclaimer: this is my personal view and is not intended to represent the views of the moderation team, Stack Exchange or anyone else.

- "How to preserve prints" is absolutely 100% on topic here, including "how to preserve prints if I want to store them flat".
- Asking for generalised descriptions of how to build appropriate containers would be on topic - and those generalised descriptions could reasonably include a off-site link to specific instructions.
- Asking for just a list of off-site links is off topic for all the normal reasons that we discourage collections of off-site links.

Answer (score 1):

A day late to the party, but I think preserving prints is definitely on-topic. How to store them, keep them separated, paper acidity and ink concerns, etc., are all part of the art, science, business, and knowledge of photography.

Asking for lists of links would be off-topic. However, I would hope that a few well-written answers describe actual projects, with links (if necessary) to more details about the project.